# How can I make ESLint force imports of .ts files to have a .js extension?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I want to export ESM imports from my TypeScript project. TypeScript will not append file extensions, or convert `.ts` to `.js`, so I need to add `.js` to all of my imports manually. I can't figure out how to set up ESLint to require `.js` extensions for imports of `.ts` files. My project is too big to manually check if all the imports have `.js` at the end, so I need ESLint to check it for me. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This newer plugin `eslint-plugin-require-extensions` seems to resolve this issue well. I've briefly tested it with `eslint .` and `eslint --fix .` on a couple of small projects.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-require-extensions
- https://github.com/solana-labs/eslint-plugin-require-extensions

> This is a simple eslint plugin that ensures that relative imports and exports have .js extensions.

Disclaimer: I'm not the author.

Comment: Oh, cool, that looks like what I wanted. I knew it was possible to make a computer add those three characters for me and now someone has. Thanks 

Comment: Simple and sweet

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `eslint-plugin-import` plugin to force eslint errors for missing file extensions in import sources. Specifically, the [`"import/extensions"`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/extensions.md) rule.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Edits**

Specific extensions can be prohibited by assigning them a "never" value. For example, to exclude `.ts` extensions you could provide the following:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "always",
            { "ts": "never" }
        ]
    }
}
```

<strike>Alternatively, if you want to prohibit all extensions *except* specific extensions (such as only allowing `.js`), you can provide the following:</strike> Nevermind, this doesn't work in all cases.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "never",
            { "js": "always" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't throw an error if I write .ts instead of .js.

Comment: @RickyKazuoMiller I edited the answer with two approaches that I believe will solve that issue.

Comment: If I'm importing a file named `file.ts`, the code needs to be `import './file.js';`. I don't think this extension supports that.

Comment: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2170